# Is there a way to see git diff from origin/master using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, meld

Using Visual Studio Code (version 1.11.2), I can see a side-by-side graphical diff of my current changes very easily by clicking the *Source Control* button in the left panel. But once I commit those changes to my local repository, I am unable to find a way to see the same side-by-side diff from origin/master.

In other words, is there a way to the spawn comparison tool of Visual Studio Code (version 1.11.2) to show me what I see when I do `git diff origin/master`, but in the side-by-side graphical diff too?

Comment: you can do that in the git history dialog.

Comment: Not sure why this simple feature missing in VSCode compared with IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can use an extension for this.

Two good options:

**Gitlens:** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens

With this one, you can use the `>GitLens: Open Changes with...` action to compare with any branch (local or remote).

You also can use **Git History**: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory

You can see the entire file history and compare with the current version with the `>Git: View File History` action.

Comment: The Gitlens "Compare Line Revision With Previous" context menu option is genius!

Comment: Note that this has changed as of gitlens release 9.0.0 
https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/releases/tag/v9.0.0

Comment: In the new version, use the "Open Changes with Revision..." in the menu option of the tab.

Comment: Hm, GitLens opens a read-only diff. Is there a way to sync individual changes into HEAD?

Comment: It seems to only compare the parent project.  Is it possible to be able to select a submodule to compare somehow?

Comment: The current version of Gitlens doesn't have a command called `Open Changes with...`

Answer (score 30):

From *[Using Version Control in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_vs-code-as-git-diff-tool)*:

Add this to the Git configuration file, like `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

When using `git difftool HEAD HEAD^`, Git will ask if to use **Visual Studio Code**.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is also support for merge?

Comment: This is what I am looking for but the change did nothing for me on Version 2.18.0

Comment: @HackSlash I am on git 2.18.0 too, may be you can see the original doc [Using Version Control in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_vs-code-as-git-diff-tool)

Comment: This command does make vscode my default editor. That's cool. Thanks. `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is good if you want to compare a single file from HEAD to some commit.
On the other hand, if you need to diff all your files with another branch, Git Lens also provide solution for that:
Go to source control tab on the side(1) > click on `BRANCHES`(2) > right click on the desired branch (like dev - 3)

[image]

Now, a menu will open, choose `compare with HEAD`

[image]

- You could also do the same with commits, if in phase (2) you'll choose `COMMITS` instead.
- You could also use `cmnd+shift+p` or `ctrl+shift+p` and type `GitLens: Compare HEAD with`, and then choose the specific wanted commit/branch.

Answer (score 11):

I use [GitLens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) as well. Go to `Source Control` tab, right click on file you want to compare with `origin/master` (or other) branch. From the menu choose `Open Changes with...` and pick a branch.

[image: Compare local file changes to master]

Answer (score 0):

I am using vscode with [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) 
The most convenient way to see diff from origin/$branch is to use git merge tool. 
For example if I want to compare local and remote **develop** branch
I will use the following command

```bash
git merge --no-commit --no-ff origin/develop
```

And the most exiting thing is that **I can see all the changes in all the files from the gitlents extension tab and side by side** and in case I don't want to merge there is a command

```bash
git merge --abort
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In case the you are not in synch with the master branch, and your changes are commited to current branch, do `git merge master`, note the changes, then remove them with `git reset`.

Otherwise, if you have already merged the latest changes from master to your current branch, you might want to just use the `File history` section of the `Source Control` side panel. The icon highlighted in yellow in the image below opens a side-to-side file compare.

[image]

PS: The Git Lens "Open changes with..." is a nice solution, but this is a paid extension, which stops working after trial period.

Answer (score -4):

From [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/user_ed/2016/02/08/visual-studio-code-all-the-git-features/)

Viewing Diffs

> Our Git tooling supports viewing of Diffs within VS Code. Click the file in the Git view to display a side-by-side view. This allows you to compare your current file with a previous version of it:

Answer (score -7):

It doesn't use Visual Studio Code, but if you just want to see a quick summary of changes... just start a PR from the branch on GitHub.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to see diff between staged/uncommitted changes etc, also you have to push each commit just to see the diff