# Can VS Code show changes, which are available via git diff --cached

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I did `git add .`, so the files are now in a stage, and VS Code stopped displaying those circles (green meaning 'new' line etc).

The changes are not visible through `git diff` but I can see them with `git diff --cached`, is this possible to somehow tell VS Code to use that method, when displaying those marks?

In other words, I would love to see changes (the marks on the margin) between current stage and the last commit.

Comment: Try gitlens or githistory extension.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711528/4901118

Comment: @HeisAif - Thanks, but no, it doesn't help, I already do have gitlense, I know I can open 'source control' and also 'Open changes with revision...'. This works indeed, but I want to see my changes straight away, in the editor, without opening anything special.